# How can I use DataTables in an Electron application?

Tags: html, datatables, electron, bulma

I tried adding this code to my app and it doesn't seem to load the DataTables. I included the latest datatables CDN links into the head.

I basically wanted this: http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/3245/ on one of my screens in my electron app, so i got the source and attempted to see if it renders but nothing shows up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bulma Version 0.6.0 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.js" Datatables></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kingkode.com/datatables.editor.lite/js/altEditor/dataTables.altEditor.free.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
    table.dataTable tbody>tr.selected,
    table.dataTable tbody>tr>.selected {
      background-color: #A2D3F6;
    }
  </style>

  <title>DataTables</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataSet = [
          ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
          ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
          ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
          ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
          ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
          ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
          ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
          ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
          ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
          ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
          ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
          ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
          ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
          ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
          ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
          ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
          ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
          ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
          ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
          ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
          ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
          ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
          ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
          ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
          ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
          ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
          ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
          ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
          ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
          ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
          ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
          ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
          ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
          ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
          ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
          ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
        ];

        var columnDefs = [{
          title: "Name"
        }, {
          title: "Position"
        }, {
          title: "Office"
        }, {
          title: "Extn."
        }, {
          title: "Start date"
        }, {
          title: "Salary"
        }];

        var myTable;

        myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          data: dataSet,
          columns: columnDefs,
          dom: 'Bfrtip', // Needs button container
          select: 'single',
          responsive: true,
          altEditor: true, // Enable altEditor
          buttons: [{
              text: 'Add',
              name: 'add' // do not change name
            },
            {
              extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
              text: 'Edit',
              name: 'edit' // do not change name
            },
            {
              extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
              text: 'Delete',
              name: 'delete' // do not change name
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "bbLjzspf"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to clean it up a bit but I still don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting ?

Comment: No, it just doesn’t show up... the funny thing is that when I preview the code locally in a browser it works just fine.

Comment: Can you remove window.onload function and try ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Datatables with electron requires you to download the packages using node package manager (npm), after that you need to require the downloaded modules within your script tag like this:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('datatables.net')();
```